# Как добавить кастомное поле в выборку, которого нету в базе данных? Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, postgresql

Делаю выборку
`MyModel::find()->select('id, name_loc, description_loc, custom_field');`

custom_field - мое кастомное поле, котрого нету в базе. Как правильно туда что-то передать в зависимости в какой модели идет поиск. Использую ActiveRecord

Answer (score 0):

```
(new \yii\db\Query())
        ->select(['id', 'name_loc', 'description_loc'])
        ->addSelect(['custom_field' => new Expression('id + 1')])
        ->from(MyModel::tableName())
```

Comment: Так не получится. Поля нет в описании модели и соответственно оно не выберется. Нужно добавить поле в `Model`. Описать его в `rules` и только после этого выбирать в запросе.

Comment: да, Вы правы. как вариант можно использовать: (new \yii\db\Query())
            ->select(['id', 'name_loc', 'description_loc'])
            ->addSelect(['custom_field' => new Expression('id + 1')])
            ->from(MyModel::tableName())

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]